# Syntax error in R SQLDF, "Error in rsqlite_send_query"

Tags: sql, r

I have a dataframe named as "model_probabilities" in R. i need to specifically use SQL queries on that. So I am using sqldf module. All the three columns mentioned in question have values between 0 to 1 .I tried to run following query in R.

```
col1=sqldf("select
CASE 
        when ( select max(v) from ( values(local_schools__good) , (local_schools__fair) , (local_schools__poor)) as value (v)) in (local_schools__good) then 'local_schools__good'
        when (select max(v) from ( values(local_schools__good) , (local_schools__fair) , (local_schools__poor)) as value (v)) in (local_schools__fair) then 'local_schools__fair'
        when ( select max(v) from ( values(local_schools__good) ,  (local_schools__fair) , (local_schools__poor)) as value (v)) in (local_schools__poor) then 'local_schools__poor'
        else 'None'
        end 
           from model_probabilities")
```

I am getting the following error:

> Error in rsqlite_send_query(conn@ptr, statement) : near "(": syntax error

Comment: How are you connecting to the database, ie, how are you setting up your username/password, specifying the database, etc?

Comment: Generally one needs to use `paste` to insert the values of named objects that exist in the R workspace. You should more completely describe the schema of your SQL tables and what variables are supposed to be in the R workspace, since I cannot tell what is what from your generating code snippet.

Comment: I have a dataframe named as "model_probabilities" in R. i need to specifically use SQL queries on that. So I am using sqldf module. All the three columns mentioned in question have values between 0 to 1.

Comment: What is `values()?` Your own defined function? As of now, that is not proper SQL syntax and hence the error. Please describe what you are attempting to do.

Comment: Please review [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: This might sound silly, but have you tried putting the query on 1 line and completely restarting your IDE?